# No module named 'google' after moving project to a new machine

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, pycharm, google-cloud-storage

I've been developing a project in PyCharm on another machine, and it's been working fine. However, after I cloned it to a new machine and started working with it in a new PyCharm environment, I'm unable to get past the import statements when running it locally using Flask.

main.py:

```
from google.cloud import firestore, storage
```

Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Installed versions:

```
Python                   3.9.13
google-api-core          2.11.0
google-api-python-client 2.97.0
google-auth              2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
google-cloud-core        2.3.2
google-cloud-firestore   2.11.1
google-cloud-storage     2.10.0
```

I've installed requirements.txt using pip, had PyCharm install the packages, and also tried:

```
pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-firestore
pip install google-api-python-client
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
pip install google-cloud
pip install google-cloud-storage
pip install google.cloud.storage
pip install google.cloud
```

and they all show "Requirement already satisfied."

I've also uninstalled and reinstalled google-cloud-storage

Both 'pip list' and 'pip show google-cloud' show the components installed, but they won't import.

This seems like a common error, but none of the solutions I've found have worked. I've encountered some environment variables on the new machine I had to update to get this far, like the path to the Python installation in pyvenv.cfg. Is there something else I missed that will point the thing to the installed packages?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update: Thanks for the input! I think I found the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

When I first created the virtual environment, I used a non-standard name, "wag" instead of venv, and it looks like part of the new system is trying to use venv, though the "wag" environment is active.

pip show google-cloud:

```
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.34.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users]owner\pycharmprojects\site\wag\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

import sys; print(sys.path) (note the last two entries):

```
['C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pycharmprojects\\Site', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pycharmprojects\\Site', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\python39', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pycharmprojects\\pythonProject\\venv', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Pycharmprojects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

So I guess the question is now: How do I get everything to use the correct environment?
Looking at the Run/Debug configuration, I found that it was set to use an interpreter in the venv environment. There are options that use the wag environment, however, using those doesn't alleviate the problem, I suspect because the version is wrong. The venv option looks like the correct version, 3.9, however the wag options are all 3.12.

"python --version" shows version 3.9.13. The original machine/env uses 3.9, and that's the version installed onto the new machine. Python 3.12 doesn't exist on either machine.

Here's what "import sys; print(sys.path)" shows on the 3.12 environment:

```
C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Site\wag\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Site\main.py 
['C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Site', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Site', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Site\\wag', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Site\\wag\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The error changes a bit under the 3.12 options:

```
from google.cloud import firestore, storage
ImportError: cannot import name 'firestore' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I think I saw somewhere that Firestore doesn't support Python > 3.10, so I think the version I actually have is what I need, not 3.12.

Comment: Probably you've configured PyCharm to use a different version of Python than is used by pip.

Comment: Show us the output of `pip show google-cloud`, particularly the Location line.

Comment: Also show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to install a virtualenv per project, install all dependencies inside that virtualenv (using pip of the virtualenv) and configure PyCharm to use the virtualenv's Python interpreter.

You can do this from within PyCharm or from outside, retroactively setting the correct options inside PyCharm. I personally find it easier to create the virtualenv and install the dependencies outside of PyCharm or using its integrated terminal. This way you can first make sure the project actually runs. Problems are easier to google, too.

Once that is done it mostly only about choosing the virtualenvs Python interpreter inside the PyCharm settings.